# How to order a json based on an array?

Tags: javascript, angular

how to order json based on another array

```
const data = [
    {
        "Taken By": "",
        "Worked Accounts": 4,
        "Code": "ABCD",
        "Contactable Accounts": 3,
    },
    {
        "Taken By": "Ram",
        "Code": "ABCD",
        "Taken By": "Ram",
        "Worked Accounts": 2,
        "Contactable Accounts": 1,
    },
    {
        "Taken By": "krish",
        "Code": "ABCD",
        "Worked Accounts": 2,
        "Contactable Accounts": 2,
    },
    {
        "Taken By": "",
        "Worked Accounts": 9,
        "Code": "XYZ",
        "Contactable Accounts": 4,
    },
    {
        "Taken By": "Jack",
        "Code": "XYZ",
        "Worked Accounts": 5,
        "Contactable Accounts": 0,
    },
    {
        "Taken By": "krish",
        "Code": "XYZ",
        "Worked Accounts": 4,
        "Contactable Accounts": 4,
    }
]

const orderarray = ['Code', 'TakenBy']

const result = [
    {
        "Code": "ABCD",
        "Taken By": "",
        "Worked Accounts": 4,
        "Contactable Accounts": 3,
    },
    {
        "Code": "ABCD",
        "Taken By": "Ram",
        "Worked Accounts": 2,
        "Contactable Accounts": 1,
    },
    {
        "Code": "ABCD",
        "Taken By": "krish",
        "Worked Accounts": 2,
        "Contactable Accounts": 2,
    },
    {
        "Code": "XYZ",
        "Taken By": "",
        "Worked Accounts": 9,
        "Contactable Accounts": 4,
    },
    {
        "Code": "XYZ",
        "Taken By": "Jack",
        "Worked Accounts": 5,
        "Contactable Accounts": 0,
    },
    {
        "Code": "XYZ",
        "Taken By": "krish",
        "Worked Accounts": 4,
        "Contactable Accounts": 4,
    }
]

const result = (Object.assign(orderarray, data));
```

Comment: Which steps have you tried yet? Not answering the question but trying you to help by asking some related questions: Can you order the array by some property name stored in a variable (assuming the property values can be compared using < and >)? What do you think does it mean to sort by multiple criteria?

Comment: const result = (Object.assign(orderarray, data));

Answer (score 0):

Order an array is only use a function that return 1,-1 or 0 if the two elements to compare are less,greater,or equal.

```
result=this.data.sort((a:any,b:any)=>{
  this.orderarray.forEach(field=>{
     if (a[field]>b[field]) return 1;
     if (a[field]<b[field]) return -1;
  })
  return 0
})
```

```
  result = this.data.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    let order = 0;

    this.orderarray.forEach((field) => {
      if (!order) {
        if (a[field] > b[field]) order = 1;
        if (a[field] < b[field]) order = -1;
      }
    });
    return order;
  });
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mflkmq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: can u share the snippet

Comment: @VishnuShenoy, I added a stackblitz in the answer. See that sort compare two elements in the array "a" and "b". with each pair of elements loop over "orderArray". The first loop compare the values of a.Code and b.Code if both values compare the values of a["Taken By"] and b["Taken By] (else return 1 or -1) and so on. NOTE: your orderarray should be `orderarray = ['Code', 'Taken By']` -see the "space" between Taken and By, the elements of the array must be one "property" of the elements of the data array.

Comment: the expected result is Code should come in 1st index and Taken By in 2nd index. but the result is sam as data in the link provided

Comment: sorry, I updated the answer

Comment: Side note: by using a regular for-of loop (instead of .forEach) you could use your first approach which returns immediately if two properties are compared with result 1 or -1. This will potentially skip some unnecessary iterations.